# Positivity of an integral

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis

Let $f(x)=x-\theta(x)$, and for $x\ge 2$ let $J(x)=\int_x^{\infty}\frac{f(y)(1+\log y)}{y^2\log^2 y}dy$.  Furthermore, $J(2)>0$. Suppose $J(x)>0$ when $f(x)=0$.  Does it follow that $J(x)>0$ for all $x\geq 2$?  Note that if $f$ were continuous, this would be the case. $\theta$ is the Chebyshev theta.  The integral appears in Rosser and Schoenfeld, and also in a paper by Nicolas, and it is related to the sum of prime reciprocals.  Its positivity is equivalent to the Riemann Hypothesis (reference NA).

Comment: As with your previous question, this post is greatly lacking in context (including the origin of that particular integral). Furthermore, it's probably unlikely that your "suppose" assertion is actually true; do you want the answer to your question to be "yes", as would be vacuously valid?

Comment: Context: $J(x)$ appears in old papers of Schoenfeld and Nicolas and it is related to the sum of prime reciprocals

Comment: Instead of clarifying in comments, please edit the original post to include the improvements.